# Problem connecting to PPTP VPN in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, pptp

I have a VPN client configured for using PPTP under Ubuntu 9.10 (the alpha version, but fully up to date). The configuration has everything enabled except for EAP (I found I had to uncheck that to make it work).

It worked fine until Tuesday of this week. It now fails with a message: "VPN Connection Failed".

The message in /var/log/messages when it worked on Tuesday is:

```
Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5//nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.  
pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0  
Using interface ppp0  
ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2  
CHAP authentication succeeded  
MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled  
local  IP address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  
remote IP address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  
primary   DNS address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  
secondary DNS address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Now it has changed to:

```
Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5//nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.  
pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0  
Using interface ppp0  
ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3  
Modem hangup  
Connection terminated.  
Exit.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10 alpha; I'm using the standard network-manager applet to configure it (but have also tried kVPNc and manual configuration). The VPN is working fine-- I can connect to it using an XP virtual machine running on the system.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Yes-- the key was to edit VPN, click on advanced, in the PPTP Advanced Options dialog, unselect "EAP".

Comment: Davesnyd - awesome that you figured out the problem; could you please write that up as an answer to your own question, and accept it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to edit VPN, click on advanced, in the PPTP Advanced Options dialog, unselect "EAP".

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but this may be related: https://superuser.com/questions/91009/vpn-pptp-connects-intermittently-on-mac-os-x

(I can't seem to be able to make comments, I guess I don't have enough karma yet, so, there).